# Python slicing does not change the sliced array's value

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to test the slicing feature of Python numpy. For the following code, I would expect the output be [101,100,101,100,101,100].

```
x = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,0])
y = x
y = y + 100
x
```

But it returns [1,0,1,0,1,0]. Why? I thought slicing modifies the original array as well.

Comment: Instead of `y = y + 100`, try `y += 100`.

Comment: @JimWright Not exactly.  With a numpy array, `y += 100` will operate in-place.  `y = y + 100` will create a new numpy array and assign it to `y`.  Try it

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Just remembered that and deleted my comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is a function, which returns a new array. By running `y + 100` you ran a function, which returned a pointer to a new array, which you stored in `y`.

If you were to run `y[0] = 5`, `x` would change as well.

**Added in edit:**

`+` is the implicit version of `numpy.add(y, 100)`, which broadcasts 100 to `[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]`. It then sums both arrays, and thus it has to return a new one.

[numpy.add doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)

Also, as mentioned in the comments, if you wanted `x` to change, you could use `y += 100` which maps to `y = y.__iadd__(100)`.

Comment: Great. So you are saying by "y=x", y points to the same memory location as x does. And y[0] points to the location of position 0 starting at location x. However, y = y+100 moves pointer y to another memory location different than x. But then y += 100 operates in place and therefore modifies the array x is pointing to?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the feature of NumPy slicing to reflect the values in the original array like

```
x = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,0])
y = x
y[:] = y + 100
x  # will change
```

Hope it helps